# RxJS Use source observable as source and input value in operator function

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have this operator function `multiply` that I would like to be able to pass the source observable to and a input value within the source. I can achieve this with a `switchMap` but then I also need to pass the source to the operator which seems a bit redundant.

```
  source$ = of({
    val: 5,
    factor: 6,
    factorTwo: 3
  });

  multiply(factor: number) {
    return (source: Observable<{ val: number }>) => source.pipe(map(value => value.val * factor))
  }

  simpleUsage$ = this.source$.pipe(this.multiply(1))

  WithFactorOne$ = this.source$.pipe(
    switchMap(x => this.multiply(x.factor)(of(x)))
  )

  WithFactorTwo$ = this.source$.pipe(
    switchMap(x => this.multiply(x.factorTwo)(of(x)))
  )
```

If I use `map` the source is passed, but the return type is `(source: Observable<{val: number;}>) => Observable<number>` rather than `Observable<Number>` like I get when using `switchMap`. Is it possible to achieve this without passing the source manually?

```
  desieredFactor$ = this.source$.pipe(
    map(x => this.multiply(x.factor))
  )
```

This is a simple example but the general issue is shown. Should I rethink the solution? Can this be accomplished in another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could allow passing a function to `multiply`, which would then allow you to use any value from the emitted source:

```js
interface Example {
  val: number;
  factor: number;
  factorTwo: number;
}

source$ = of<Example>({
  val: 5,
  factor: 6,
  factorTwo: 3
});

multiply(factor: number | ((source: Example) => number)) {
  return (source: Observable<Example>) =>
    source.pipe(map(value => {
      const f = typeof factor === 'function' ? factor(value) : factor;
      return value.val * f;
    }))
}

// Use with number
simpleUsage$ = this.source$.pipe(this.multiply(1))

// Use with function
WithFactorOne$ = this.source$.pipe(this.multiply(x => x.factor))
WithFactorTwo$ = this.source$.pipe(this.multiply(x => x.factorTwo))
```

---

Added note:

If you were to put a return type on the multiply function above, it would read:

```ts
function multiply(factor: number | ((source: Example) => number)): OperatorFunction<Example, number>
```

Since `map` is an operator function itself, you don't need to manually construct your own by defining a function over a source observable, you can just return the `map`

Like this:

```ts
function multiply(
  factor: number | ((source: Example) => number)
): OperatorFunction<Example, number> {

  return map(value => {
    const f = typeof factor === 'function' ? factor(value) : factor;
    return value.val * f;
  });
  
}
```

Comment: A callback really did the trick!

Comment: `(source: Observable<Example>) => source.pipe(map(...` can be refactored to `map(...` and it'll be a bit clearer that this is just a new operator that specializes the `map` operator function.

Answer (score 1):

`multiply` shouldn't concern itself with streams at all, just do the multiplication. It could look like this:

```
type FactorDefinition = {
    factorValue?: number,
    factorName?: 'factor' | 'factorTwo',
};

const multiply = (
  inputValue,
  { factorName, factorValue }: FactorDefinition,
) => {
  const multiplier = factorName ? inputValue[factorName] : factorValue;

  return inputValue.val * multiplier;
};

const simpleUsage$ = source$.pipe(
  map((value) => multiply(value, { factorValue: 1 }))
);

withFactorOne$ = source$.pipe(
  map((value) => multiply(value, { factorName: 'factor' }))
);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-2un7xf?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts